# read multiple values from a property file using bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, properties

Would like to read multiple values from a property file using a shell script

My properties files looks something like below, the reason I added it following way was to make sure, if in future more students joins I just need to add in in the properties file without changing any thing in the shell script.

**student.properties**

```
total_student=6
student_name_1="aaaa"
student_name_2="bbbb"
student_name_3="cccc"
student_name_4="dddd"
student_name_5="eeee"
```

When I run below script I not getting the desired output, for reading the student names from properties file

**student.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
. /student.properties

i=1
while [ $i -lt $total_student ]
do
    {
        std_Name=$student_name_$i
        echo $std_Name

        #****** my logic *******

    } || {
        echo "ERROR..."
    }
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Output is something like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I understand the script is not getting anything for *$student_name_* hence only *$i* value is getting printed.

Hence, wanted to know how to read values from the properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do variable name interpolation with `${!foo}`. If `$foo` is `"bar"`, then `${!foo}` gives you the value of `$bar`. In your code that means changing

```
std_Name=$student_name_$i
```

to

```
var=student_name_$i
std_Name=${!var}
```

Alternatively, you could store the names in an array. Then you wouldn't have to do any parsing.

**student.properties**

```
student_names=("aaaa" "bbbb" "cccc" "dddd" "eeee")
```

**student.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
. /student.properties

for student_name in "${student_names[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indirect expansion:

```
std_Name=student_name_$i
echo "${!std_Name}"
```

the expression `${!var}` basically evaluates the variable twice:

1. first evaluation: `student_name_1`
2. second evaluation: `foo`

Note that this is [rarely a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Think_before_using_indirection) and that using an array is almost always preferred.

Comment: Why is it not  good idea? I agree in this particular case using an array is better but variable indirection can be very useful.